# If one travels the circumference of their Techum on Shabbos, do they say Tefilas HaDerech?

Tags: shabbat, travel, eruv-techumin, tefilat-haderech

If one traveled the circumference around their Techum on Shabbos (about 12.5k Amos = 2π * 2000), do they have any obligation to say Tefilas HaDerech, being that they traveled more than 2.8 miles (approximate measurement of a Parsa)? And this is assuming there are no nearby houses or metropolitan cities.

[image: Traveling along circumference of Techum]

In other words, is there ever a case where someone may/must say Tefilas HaDerech on Shabbos?

Comment: I think the techum is a rectangle

Comment: Someone who has to travel outside the techum for pikuach nefesh (soldier, doctor)

Comment: @Heshy, not only a rectangle, but the sides are specifically in the four compass directions. (I have a feeling that if we looked closely at NE US, and took a rectangle around one town, and then redid it with every building that rectangle included, etc... All of subrban Boston to somewhere outside of Fairfax VA, slightly beyond Washington DC, could be the diagonal of a single "city" for techum Shabbos.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Even in that case would you say tefilas haderech?  It's a bakasha and if the travel itself isn't that dangerous maybe you wouldn't say it on Shabbos.

Comment: @Heshy I didn't say otherwise and I suspect that's what the OP was getting at with this question. My gut instinct though is to say it if you really did need to travel.

Comment: @micah technically more of a trapezoid (unless you're right on the equator)

Comment: This question would apply in the weekday also?

Comment: @GershonGold I believe in the weekday, if the trip is dangerous, then it should qualify for Tefilas HaDarech, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tefilas HaDerech is said on Shabbos if one needs to travel (for example for childbirth, danger, etc.)

[See here](https://din.org.il/2014/07/22/%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9A/)

> הנוסע בשבת מפני הסכנה, או שמלוה חולה שיש בו סכנה, חייב לומר תפילת
> הדרך.

However Ishei Yisrael 50:28 says that one should never say Tefilas HaDerech on Shabbos. [See here](http://beinenu.com/sites/default/files/alonim/195_47_77.pdf) However then makes exceptions.

> אין לומר תפילת הדרך בשבת,   דאין לבקש צרכיו בשבת . ( אשי ישראל פ"נ הע'
> כח ששמע מרבינו. גם בתורת היולדת פכ"ב נקט שיתכן שאין לומר תפילת הדרך
> בשבת. והוסיף, שאם הדרך מסוכנת, וכמו"כ בנסיעה של יולדת בסכנה והרכב נוסע
> במהירות רבה ומסכן אותה, יש לומר תפילת הדרך, כדאיתא בשו"ע סי' רפח ס"י,
> ובסי' תקעו סי"ג, שזועקים ומתחננים בשבת על חולה שיש בו סכנת היום)